# SecTrustEvaluate() returns kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure in mac 10.10 whereas prev versions return kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure why?

Tags: macos, ssl-certificate, keychain, truststore, osx-server

Till MAC 10.9 when we call the below function

```
OSStatus SecTrustEvaluate(SecTrustRef trust, SecTrustResultType *result);
```

we use to get return value as "kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure" where as from MAC 10.10 I'm getting response as "kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure"?

Why it is happening so?

==================================================================================

here is the code for evaluating SSL Certificate

```
    //=====================================================================================================================
//     EvaluateSSLCert
//          For a given readstream, evaluates the server ssl certificate
//          returns YES - certificate valid
//          NO - invalid certificate
//=====================================================================================================================
-(BOOL)EvaluateSSLCert
{
     BOOL bValidCert = YES;
     SecTrustRef trust = NULL;
     SecPolicyRef policy = NULL;
     OSStatus retStat;
     CFArrayRef certArray = NULL;
     SecTrustResultType result;
     SecPolicySearchRef search;


          certArray = (CFArrayRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(m_StreamRead, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates);
          retStat = SecPolicySearchCreate(CSSM_CERT_X_509v3, &CSSMOID_APPLE_TP_SSL, NULL, &search);
          retStat = SecPolicySearchCopyNext(search, &policy);
          CFRelease(search);
          retStat = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(certArray, policy, &trust); 
          if(retStat == 0)
          {
               retStat = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, NULL); //set to default settings
               retStat = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &result);
               if(retStat == 0)
               {
                    NSLogSecuredString(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG,"<EvaluateSSLCert> SecTrustEvaluate succeeded");
                    if(result == kSecTrustResultDeny || result == kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure)
                    {
                         NSLogSecuredString(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG,"<EvaluateSSLCert> Invalid Cert. SecTrustEvaluate result = %d", result);
                         bValidCert = NO;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         //valid cert
                         NSLogSecuredString(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG,"<EvaluateSSLCert> SecTrustEvaluate result = %d", result);
                    }
               }
               else
                    NSLogSecuredString(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG,"<EvaluateSSLCert> SecTrustEvaluate failed");
          }
          CFRelease(policy);
          CFRelease(trust);

     return bValidCert;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone knows about it kindly share the details...

Comment: SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, NULL); // this line refers to setting the default anchor certs. we have a certificate kept in the "KeyChain Application" does this function get those details with above function call??

Answer (score -1):

kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates is no longer working on 10.10. You can try use kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust to retrieve the trust object and cert objects.

SecTrustRef trust = (SecTrustRef) CFReadStreamCopyProperty( m_StreamRead, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust);

Comment: yes I did this change and now, SecTrustEvaluate() function itself failed, it is not returning 0 :(